# Yfinance not giving precise price for cryptocurrencies in 1min time frame

Tags: python, cryptocurrency, yfinance, usd

I want to get the 1min chart of btc-usd of the past day to be able to make some analysis on it using pandas.

I tried by using yfinance and it gives me the price however the Open High Low and Close are all the same for every 1 min candle.

When I try with stocks such as AAPL or MSFT, I don't have this problem.
But I can't get accurate information for any Cryptocurrency.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

[image: Here is what I get:]

Here is my code:

```py
hist2 = yf.download(tickers = "btc-usd", period="1d", interval="1m")

print (hist2)
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tested a script using ydownload with BTC-USD and an interval of 1m and I get the same result. If I had to guess, Yahoo isn't offering OHLC data at this level at the moment.

Comment: Same result if you check the yahoo finance website. I recommend looking at investing.com for data. You can get it for free.